# Vaadin/Spring duplicated error in a ManytoMany Join

Tags: java, jpa, join, many-to-many

I have a User class and a Movie class which I want to merge into separate Lists. Once for movies that have been watched and one for the watchlist. Separately everything is fine but it seems that when I want to put them on both merges I get a duplication error even though they are saved in differently named columns.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_watch_list", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "watche_User_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "watch_Movie_id",referencedColumnName = "movieID"))
private List<Movie> watchList = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_watched_movies", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "watcheed_User_ID",referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "watched_movie_id",referencedColumnName = "movieID"))
private List<Movie> watchedMovies = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Vaadin?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Mmm, just off the top of the head, you might check your equals() methods. Make sure they exclude the records being seen as duplicates.